# REGEX Get string between comment tags ( /* string */)

Tags: php, regex

I need to get the string in between `/* */` comment tag. I am trying to parse a file and just get the strings between comment tags within it. I'm new in using regex. So any advise would be greatly appreciated. I already tried some but none are working.

Sample String Would Be. And yes there is a newline after `/*` and before `*/`

```
/*
 Comment Here
 Comment Here
*/
```

Comment: I'm using PHP. Sorry I forgot to mention it ..:)

Answer (score 4):

You haven't said what language you are using, but this regex will work for java (which doesn't require escaping of `/`):

```
(?s)/\*(.*?)\*/
```

Group 1 (ie `\1`) has the content you seek

Comment: Hi Bohemian .. I'm using PHP. Sorry I forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 2):

It's tricky if you use `/` as the delimiter because then the slashes inside the regular expression will need escaping, so use a different [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) instead:

```
"#/\*(.*?)\*/#s"
```

The `s` after the last delimiter is the [DOTALL modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what regex flavor you're looking for, but you can find a good discussion of finding comments using regular expressions [here](http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html). Check it out -- it's not a simple as several of the early answers here suggest.

However, note that the regular expressions at the site matches comments -- you'll need to then apply one of the other answers here to extract the text as needed.

Answer (score 1):

In php, use this

```
if (preg_match('%/\*(.*?)\*/%s', $subject, $matches)) {
    $result = $matches[1];
} else {
    $result = "";
}
```

You could also trim the match too if you wanted

```
$result = trim($matches[1]);
```